# NSURLConnection doesn't send data, but connects

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsmutableurlrequest

The URL is written properly, I tested it in the browser with data and it sends properly, but when I make the request, it returns that it is successful, but it does not actually write the data. Any idea?

```
- (void)writeAboutMe:(NSString *)about withIcebreaker:(NSString *)icebreaker 
{
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://nailorbail.net63.net/submit_about_and_icebreaker.php?username=%@&about=%@&icebreaker=%@",[SignInViewController getUsernameString] ,about,icebreaker];
NSLog(@"%@",urlString);
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if(conn)
    NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
else
    NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
[conn release];
}
```

Comment: The same url works in the browser?  There might be a space in the url that the browser handles gracefully, but you will have to handle yourself before you create the NSURL.  Does the call send data if the username has no spaces?

Comment: I tried trimming it using the NSCharacterSet whiteSpaceAndNewlineCharacterSet, and even with that, it still doesn't send

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be an encoding issue. What kinds of characters are in `getUsernameString`, `about`, and `icebreaker`? As Maudicus mentioned, you need to handle special characters in the URL yourself.

Try:

```
urlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have set up an asynchronous connection. Do you implement the NSURLConnection delegate protocol methods? Are any of them being called?

The creation of the connection instance doesn't say anything about it's success.

Check out some tutorials, [like this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXQiEfjiYns).